# Making specific operator to be self-adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose an operator $f:V\to V$ has the following matrix in some basis $$A_f=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.$$ Is it possible to equip $V$ with the inner product in order to make this operator self-adjoint?

**Proof:** Suppose we can equip $V$ with inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$ such that the operator $f$ becomes self-adjoint.  But we know that roots of characteristic polynomial of self-adjoint operator  are real numbers. Since characteristic polynomial  can be calculated for any basis we see that actually its roots are $\{-1,\pm i\}$. Contradiction.

Is it correct reasoning?

Comment: Yes, but I would be more explicit, suppose $f v = i v$ then $\langle fv ,v \rangle = -i \|v\|^2$ and $\langle v ,f v \rangle = i \|v\|^2$ which would contradict $f$ being self adjoint.

Comment: @copper.hat, but if $V$ is real vector space and $i$ is root of characteristic polynomial then we cannot assume that $f(v)=iv$ because we are in real space. But if we consider complexification of $f$ which I denote by $f_{\mathbb{C}}$ then we can do that. I guess this is what you are doing but probably you did not mention. I just ask it in order to be sure :)

Comment: Just look at the 'real' version of the complex eigenvalues: Since $A_f$ has an eigenvalue at $i$ here are linearly independent $u,v$ such that $f u = -v, f v = u$. Now look at $\langle f u , v \rangle$ and $\langle u, f v \rangle$.

Comment: @copper.hat, Nice! In your comment you said "Yes, but I would be more explicit". But nothing is wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: Your reasoning is good.